# Can I / how do I get Windows 10 to display password requirements to users?

Tags: windows-10, passwords

A user of Windows 10 recently was asked to update her password when she was logged out of her computer, but none of the requirements for passwords were listed.  Of course since she was logged out of the system she couldn't look up anywhere what the password requirements were.  So she spent a good amount of time trying to guess passwords that would meet the requirements, before she came to me and we figured one out that worked - which has actually weakened the security because now - for a bit - I know her password.

Is it possible to have Windows 10 display the password requirements when it is asking users to update their passwords?

Comment: You can add this detail on desktop background on log-off screen or you may also display a message when user press `CTRL + ALT + DEL`. See [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-message-text-for-users-attempting-to-log-on).

Comment: A better approach would be to have the users be educated in general on good security. It could even be a security policy that everyone signs when entering the company.

Comment: @NiKiZe users are educated in general on good security, but that has nothing to do with knowing a specific password requirement policy.  Also important is that IT and InfoSec people have realistic expectations of users.

Comment: First test for new employees, enter a valid password, if they fail that their probation period is over. That is realistic. Or maybe you have an odd password requirements.

Comment: Again, you should think about having realistic expectations of users.  If you think IT is the number one concern of everyone in the organization, you're going to design and implement incredibly bad security systems for the organization.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options possible. One of them is already implemented in my organization:

---

### Background image on login screen

Add important information like password rules on desktop background image.

However, if you do not have a common image for all users, this will not work. Also, if users are allowed to change background, then too, this will not work.

---

### Logon Message

Add a message when user tries to login. This can easily be done by editing group policy. You can find more details [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-message-text-for-users-attempting-to-log-on).

Follow these steps to add a logon message:

1. Login to the domain controller machine with the administrator account.
2. Open `Group Policy Management Editor`, click on `Computer Configuration`, expand `Policies`, expand `Windows Settings`, expand `Security Settings`, expand `Local Policies`, click on `Security Options`.
3. On the right pane look for the policy `Interactive Logon : Message text for users attempting to log on`. This security setting specifies a text message that is displayed to users when they log on. You can paste the Logon text that is to be displayed to the users before they log in. Click on Apply and OK.
4. On the right pane look for the policy `Interactive Logon : Message title for users attempting to log on`. This security setting allows the title to appear in the title bar of the window that contains the Interactive logon.Type the title text and click on Apply and OK.
5. On the client computer open the command prompt and run the command `gpupdate`.
6. Log off from the client computer. Hold `CTRL+ALT` and press `DEL`. You must find the logon banner. Click on OK to login to the computer.

Comment: Thank you, but if I understand correctly this message will always displayed every time a user is prompted to log on, not just when they are asked to change their password.  I think that would be confusing.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In my organization, this is used to display important information to users. Password policy along with other useful information is always displayed as background image on all systems.